# Jquery: Variable not initialized in callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following code snippet in Javascript-Jquery:

```
var result = "";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: { 'val': $val }
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data); // shows right response
    result = data;
    alert(result); // shows right response
});
alert(result); // shows nothing
```

Even though I initialized result in the callback, I get nothing when I alert the result variable (it is still "")? Why is this?

Comment: .done is async, bottom alert happens right away

Comment: That must be it,  thanks! How do I make it .done happen before the last alert, then?

Comment: There's a way to make sync ajax call but why? Implement all your needed functionality for result inside of .done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the ajax call is run asynchronously.  Just because the second alert is after the ajax call, you still have to either a: write a callback method to fire when the call completes or, b: complete the ajax call synchronously.  See jquery ajax documentation for the async property and its description.

Answer (score 1):

Is is simple. The `alert(result)` code is executed before the `done` callback. So, the `result` variable is empty. The `done` callback is called asynchronously after the alert call.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This becasue the mode of ajax now you use is the Asynchronous ...i have a example for you that it's as follow:

```
var result = "";
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'update.php',
data: { 'val': $val' }
}).done(function(data) {
     alert(1, data);   // shows right response
     result = data;
     alert(2, result); //shows right response
});
alert(3, result) // shows nothing
```

if you want to use the Synchronous...look at the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for async variable
i hope it's useful to you:)